# sorting 3D matrix by using 2D matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, vector, 3d

Hello I am trying to sort a 3D coordinates matrix (3 columns and unlimited rows) by using the sorting in a 2D coordinates matrix (2 columns and unlimited rows):

```
A=[x1 y1 z1;x2 y2 z2;xn yn zn];

B=[xn yn;x1 y1;x2 y2];
```

Example:

A=[87 45 47;87 66 47;80 40 48;81 41 48;87 45 48;87 66 48;69 39 49;73 39 49;79 40 49;81 71 49;86 67 49;70 39 50;74 38 50;79 40 50;82 70 50;85 68 50;71 39 51;75 38 51];

B=[87 45;87 45;81 41;80 40;79 40;79 40;75 38;74 38;73 39;71 39;70 39;69 39;87 66;87 66;86 67;85 68;82 70;81 71];

I would like to sort A based on B, which means I would like to have A in the end as:

`Anew=[xn yn zn;x1 y1 z1;x2 y2 z2]`;

this is an example of my data. A is a matrix of xyz coordinate and B is xy only.

Is their any way of doing it or maybe someone can try to help me out ?

***EDIT: I used the method proposed by Jan and its working. Thank you and sorry if I didn't give enough information in my initial post.***

Comment: Please can you add an example using actual data

Comment: Where's the 3D matrix? `A` is 2D too.

Comment: and does B contain all of the x1 to xn, y1 to yn from A? Are those values exactly the same and are there no more elements in B?

Comment: @grsgs Use a minimal input data for `A` and `B` and show us the expected output, `Anew`? Please add these info into the question and not post as comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you want to reorder the rows of A such that they the first two columns of this matrix are equal to (hence match the order of) the matrix B. First of all, the rows in B are not unique, so the solution will not be unique.

Anyway, one approach would involve sorting both rows to obtain the desired new ordering. The approach is somewhat cumbersome, but works like this:

First, obtain the ordering after a sorting action on `A(:,1:2)` and `B`:

```
[~, orderA] = sortrows(A(:,1:2));
[~, orderB] = sortrows(B);
```

Then, get the order of the action that 'inverses' the second sorting:

```
[~,orderBinv] = sort(orderB);
```

Now, to get the ordering of `A(:,1:2)` equal to the ordering of `B`, you combine the inverse sorting and sorting like this:

```
Anew = A(orderA(orderBinv),:)
```

Ok, so what we have done here is: take the inverse sorting so that a sorted version of `B` would result in the original. The sorted `B` matches a sorted `A(:,1:2)` (in case of unique rows), so applying this order to the ordering that results from sorting `A` gives us the desired result.

---

So, for the given `A'` (transposed for reading convenience)

```
87    87    80    81    87    87    69    73    79    81    86    70    74    79    82    85    71    75
45    66    40    41    45    66    39    39    40    71    67    39    38    40    70    68    39    38
47    47    48    48    48    48    49    49    49    49    49    50    50    50    50    50    51    51
```

and `B'`

```
87    87    81    80    79    79    75    74    73    71    70    69    87    87    86    85    82    81
45    45    41    40    40    40    38    38    39    39    39    39    66    66    67    68    70    71
```

the resulting `Anew'` equals

```
87    87    81    80    79    79    75    74    73    71    70    69    87    87    86    85    82    81
45    45    41    40    40    40    38    38    39    39    39    39    66    66    67    68    70    71
47    48    48    48    49    50    51    50    49    51    50    49    47    48    49    50    50    49
```

Comment: Thx Jan,this is what I was searching for, just i didn't know how to do it in MATLAB. Thx again